# boolean context of a python object

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can I use a python object in a desired boolean context? 
By default any object is `True` in boolean context.

```
>>> class Person():
...           pass
... 
>>> a=Person()
>>> bool(a)
True
```

Like `bool(0)` returns `False` and `bool(1)` returns `True`.Can i have any way to define an object to have it's boolean value either `True` or `False`.
Correct me if i'm wrong anywhere,thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Something(object):
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False  # Something is False always. 

print bool(Something())
```

Take note [`__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) has been renamed to [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) in Python 3.x

As pointed out in a comment, you would be better to define `__len__` on container like collections. When `__len__` returns 0, `bool(x)` will evaluate False. Otherwise any positive number above 1 will equate to True.

Comment: The other option is to implement `__len__` (like a container); return `0` will translate to `False` in a boolean context, any integer over 1 is `True`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Edited to include

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for pointing out the __len__ method solution to the above question.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation on Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). It first checks if your instance has a `__nonzero__` method, if not it uses a `__len__` method. The instance is False if `__nonzero__` is False or its length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

[`object.__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)
and
[`object.__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)